# Нюансы пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Как, что, почем, хорош, покупать? Можно ли написать так,а не:"Как?Что?Почем?Хорош?Покупать?" - если "покупать", по смысловой нагрузке,не является обобщающим словом. (То есть тире не ставится)

Comment: Проверьте сперва собственные запятые. "По смысловой нагрузке" в запятые не берется, а вот после "то есть" должна быть запятая. А еще ставьте пробелы после запятых — невозможно даже в смысл Вашего вопроса вникнуть!

Comment: Как,что,почем,хорош - покупать? <= Этот вариант исключаем.
Как, что, почем, хорош, покупать? 
Как? Что? Почем? Хорош? Покупать?
Какой из последних двух вариантов имеет право на жизнь?

Answer (score 2):

Я вообще не увидела смысла...

Answer (score 2):

"Хорош" вводит мозг в ступор.

А если без него, то "Как, что, почем покупать?" нормально. Без всяких тире.

Answer (score 0):

...если это слоган, то вопросительные знаки усиливают внимание на нем. И если цель-привлечение внимания целевой аудитории, то усиление смысловой нагрузки как раз к этому и приводит.